# Animating a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimage, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to animate my `UIImageView` so that it animates from height x to height y and I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.test = [self createNewBarWithValue:800 atLocation:CGPointMake(107, 43)];
   }

- (UIImageView*)createNewBarWithValue:(float)percent atLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
    UIImageView *newBar = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 107, 43)] autorelease];
    newBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];

    CABasicAnimation *scaleToValue = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.y"];
    scaleToValue.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:percent];
    scaleToValue.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    scaleToValue.duration = 1.0f;
    scaleToValue.delegate = self;

    newBar.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);

    [newBar.layer addAnimation:scaleToValue forKey:@"scaleUp"];
    CGAffineTransform scaleTo = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( 1.0f, percent );
    newBar.transform = scaleTo;

    return newBar;
}
```

However, I am not seeing anything here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear you add the `UIImageView` to your view controller's view.

e.x.

```
[self.view addSubview:test];
```

Comment: It is created in IB and I have connected the outlet as well

Comment: But you seem to be reassigning the outlet (self.test) which will lose the connection you had with the original IB created UIImageView.  If you want to scale the image view you created in IB, apply the transform to self.test; theres no need to create a new UIImageView.